# how to prevent docker from using BTRFS volumes

Tags: docker, docker-machine, btrfs

How can i disable usage of BTRFS volumes in docker ? Docker should behave as if it was installed on a normal ext4 or similar volume.

if docker detects a BTRFS file system, it seems to automatically create volumes for docker containers as BTRFS volumes.
The file system connector for docker failed OFTEN in the past, corrupting its own volumes and BTRFS volumes created by other software, especially timeshift.
Docker volumes were corrupted and no longer deleteable, same as timeshift volumes.

Answer (score -1):

Just mount `/var/lib/docker` in an ext4 volume (either a volume or a bind mount). If you're using the Snap version, uninstall it and install from APT.

If you need to delete forcibly or free space, you may run `docker system prune -a`, that will remove *everything*

Comment: "docker system prune -a" is absolutele NOT removing all the inaccessible docker volumes.
docker seems to be mismanaging the access rights and the mounting of the volumes, which makes docker USELES on certain machines with btrfs